# Force deselecting a slice from pie chart

Tags: swift, charts, swift2, pie-chart, ios-charts

I am looking for a way of forcing the slice of the pie chart to become unselected. It automatically deselects when you click out of the pie chart however I was wondering if there was a way to deselect it within a button action?

I have various buttons which displays filtered versions of the same data and, if a slice is selected when you click a button it remains selected.

Any help would be great.

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Within the function chartValueSelected which is called when a slice has been selected/highlighted, I set a global variable containing the DataSetIndex:

```
var dataSetIndexToDeselect : Int = 0
func chartValueSelected(chartView: ChartViewBase, entry: ChartDataEntry, dataSetIndex: Int, highlight: ChartHighlight) {
    dataSetIndexToDeselect = dataSetIndex  
}
```

On the button click, i unhighlight the slice by adding the following line the the IBAction:

```
@IBAction func buttonClick(sender: AnyObject) {
    pieChartView.highlightValue(xIndex: -1, dataSetIndex: dataSetIndexToDeselect, callDelegate: false)
}
```

The '-1' on the xIndex causes the 'dataSetIndexToDeselect' value to no longer be selected.

Answer (score 7):

```
 pieChart.highlightValue(nil)
```

This worked for me.
I am on `Charts (3.0.2)`, `Swift 3`, `XCode 8.3.3`.

Hope this helps someone.

Comment: Lot easier than the other answer!